# How would I optimally pack a set of tasks into a minimal number of time slots?

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of [image: n] independent tasks and [image: m] time slots of the same fixed length [image: f], each task of arbitrary length [image: <=f].

How would I distribute the tasks across time slots while minimizing [image: m]?

Comment: I'm not sure, what would the greedy solution be?

Comment: And the greedy solution guarantees that you're never more than 16% off the optimal solution IIRC.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds usable! @biziclop could you provide some reference or proof or something for that? I'm still interested in the optimal solution though, if anybody knows it?

Comment: @user511287 Actually I remembered wrong, it's slightly more than that but [here's the proof](http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/Szamitasi-modellek/H4%20A%20simple%20proof%20of%20the%20inequality%20for%20the%20FFD%20bin-packing%20algorithm.pdf).

Comment: @biziclop Thanks! Still not too bad.

Comment: @user511287 It's pretty cool and amazing that there is any kind of hard limit, when you think about how impossible finding the exact solution is and how simple the approximation.

Comment: @biziclop Indeed! And a pretty good one at that too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at bin packing problem which is NP-complete. There however exist good approximate polynomial solutions.

Refer to this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here's the FFD (first fit decreasing) algorithm, which is fast, easy to implement and pretty close to the optimal solution.

1. Sort all the tasks in descending order of cost, this will be our pending list.
2. Pick the first remaining task on the pending list.
3. Find the leftmost slot that it fits and put it in there.
4. Remove the task from the pending list.
5. While the pending list isn't empty, repeat from 2.

The worst-case performance of this algorithm is `11/9*OPT + 1`, that is at worst it will require about 22% more slots than the theoretical minimum.